# What haskell topics need to be addressed in a Real-World-Haskell style?

Tags: haskell

It has been quite some time now that RWH came out (**almost 3 years**). I was eager to get my copy after following the incremental writing of the book online (which is, I think, one of the best ways to write a book.) What a rewarding read in the midst of all the rather academic papers a haskell student usually encounters!

It was a sturdy companion on quite some trips and I refer back to it regularly.
Still, my copy started to look *pretty battered* and even though most of the content is still valid, there has been an abundance of new topics in the haskell world that would be worth covering in a similar fashion.

[image: my battered copy of rwh]

Considering the impact RWH had (and still has,) I sincerely hope that there will be a sequel some day :)
Some of the topics for a sequel that would immediately come to my mind:

- **Iteratees**
- more on **concurrent programming** in haskell
- merits and dangers of **lazy evaluation**

  - possibly covering some common libraries that deal with this
  - in particular lazy io
- new **ghc features** (e.g. the new I/O Manager, LLVM code generator)
- **Memoization**
- ..

What are the topics that the haskell community needs a RWH-style explanation for?

---

*this is a summary of the suggestions so far:*

**Concepts**

- Iteratees / lazy IO
- Arrows
- ghc event manager

**Techniques**

- generics (uniplate, syb)
- metaprogramming (Template Haskell)
- data structures (use of functional datastructures, designing data structures)
- EDSLs (designing EDSLs)
- memoization
- designing with monads
- best practices for imperative programming

**Tools**

- ThreadScope
- Advanced FFI tools (c2hs, using Haskell from C)
- cabal
- haddock
- hoogle
- Tuning the runtime, esp. GC flags
- Djinn

**Libraries**

- arrays and array programming (vector, repa, hmatrix)
- numerics (random numbers)
- parallel programming (The Par monad)
- unicode and locales (text, text-icu)
- parsing (attoparsec, tagsoup)
- networking (snap, yesod)
- web stuff (templating)
- persistance (especially no-sql storage bindings)
- graphics (cairo, sdl, opengl)
- xml (haxml)
- crypto
- processors and systems stuff

Comment: Related: [Which parts of Real World Haskell are now obsolete or considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727768/which-parts-of-real-world-haskell-are-now-obsolete-or-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's my take, biased towards the ecosystem.

**Libraries**

- arrays and array programming:

  - `vector`
  - `repa`
  - `hmatrix`
- numerics

  - random numbers
- parallel programming

  - The `Par` monad
- unicode and locales

  - `text` and `text-icu`
- parsing

  - `attoparsec`
  - `tagsoup`
- networking

  - `snap` and/or `yesod`
- web stuff

  - templating
- persistance

  - databases beyond `hdbc`
  - no-sql storage bindings
- graphics

  - `cairo`
  - `sdl`
  - `opengl`
- xml

  - `haxml`
- crypto
- processors and systems stuff

**Techniques**

- generics

  - `uniplate`
  - `syb`
- metaprogramming

  - Template Haskell
- data structures

  - designing data structures
- EDSLs

  - designing EDSLs
- memoization
- designing with monads

**Tools**

- `ThreadScope`
- Advanced FFI tools

  - `c2hs`
  - using Haskell from C
- Tuning the runtime, esp. GC flags

Comment: yes pleeeeaaasee!!! this coming from don gives me some faint hope that there indeed will be a sequel :) awesome!

Answer (score 13):

I would love to see:

- Cabal & Hoogle & Haddock (best practices for the daily `code` - `build` - `test` - `deploy` workflow)
- Available datastructures and their (real world) usage, performance and space characteristics
- Data Visualization
- Best practices for imperative programming
- Yesod & Snap
- More on Database Connectivity (SQL and NoSQL)
- More on Network Programming

The "More on..." might be better placed in a "Haskell Cookbook" though.

Comment: Not that I wouldn't love to know more about those too, but some of them are temporal - your interest in them is likely to change over time.  Data structures?  Vector, repa, and unordered containers are all rather new - what else will appear soon?  Yesod & Snap?  Two years ago it would have been Happs, then Happstack.  And don't get me started about the network side of things.

Comment: @TomMD: you're right, most of these topics don't age well at all, but IMHO there are already more than enough good to great "timeless" Haskell books.

Answer (score 12):

These are less "real worldy", but I'd like to see helpful introductions (and possible Real World applications?) to

- Djinn
- Template Haskell
- Arrows

Comment: arrows...that's a good one too! i really enjoyed [this](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2010-03-26-arrows-dependencies.html) article about this topic...

Answer (score 3):

I've been meaning to ask this exact same question!  I would buy RWH vol2 if it contained the items in the list so far.  I would also like to real world examples for (in no particular order)

- GADTs
- type families
- techniques for heterogeneous lists
- [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf) style presentation of standard typeclasses
- a fuller explanation of Edward Yang's [Type Technology Tree](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/03/type-tech-tree/)
- records / lenses

Comment: [Lenses are the coalgebras for the costate comonad](http://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/lenses-are-the-coalgebras-for-the-costate-comonad/) ??! ...omg!...never heard about that before:)

Answer (score 3):

I would love to see an "RWH approach" to functional reactive programming - a RWH version of [this](http://plucky.cs.yale.edu/soe/PPTSlides/Ch15.ppt), maybe covering Yampa or something similar. But maybe this topic is not quite "real-worldy" enough (yet)...

Answer (score 1):

I am only recently new to Haskell and have only read a few chapters of this book and [Programming in Haskell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521692695) by Graham Hutton
However, I would have to agree with [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295615/alexander-battisti) in the sense I would love to see a "Haskell Cookbook" as well as a new more updated version of RWH (As I have yet to finish this is not as important personally for me!).

**Advice** and **sample codes** to do with Dates, Generating Random Numbers and the most efficient codes to perform key algorithms (Sorting etc.) would be a great addition to any such book!

Comment: RWH has a section about random numbers in the [monad chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html)

Comment: I was referring to the possibility of this being included in a Cookbook not RWH. But thank you for the interesting link.