# Purpose And Workings of `Doc` In Real World Haskell, Ch 5

Tags: algorithm, haskell, pretty-print

[Chapter 5 of Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html) introduces a pretty-printing library, specifically with an abstract `Doc`, in the context of pretty-printing [JSON](http://www.json.org/):

> Instead of rendering straight to a string, our Prettify module will use an abstract type that we'll call Doc. By basing our generic rendering library on an abstract type, we can choose an implementation that is flexible and efficient. If we decide to change the underlying code, our users will not be able to tell.

However, (as several commentors wrote on this otherwise excellent book wrote), it's a bit hard to understand from this chapter why is `Doc` needed, or how exactly does it solve the problem. Specifically, in the context of a chapter focusing on modules, it's hard to understand the motivation given by

> If we decide to change the underlying code, our users will not be able to tell.

This, on its own, could be achieved by simply exporting a pretty printing function, and not exporting anything related to the implementation. Why is `Doc` needed, then, and how does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I self-answered this question after spending a lot of time reading chapter 5 as well as [[Hughes 95]](http://belle.sourceforge.net/doc/hughes95design.pdf) and [[Wadler 98]](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/prettier/prettier.pdf), for the following reasons:

1. The chapter simultaneously deals with many different points (e.g., JSON, pretty printing, hex formats, Haskell modules, the need for signatures, etc.).
2. The chapter moves unexpectdly between very high level and low level questions, e.g., generic pretty printing, and escaping JSON strings; somewhat strangely, the discussion of escapting begins *after* the transition from JSON-specific printing, to generic pretty-printing.
3. IIUC, [Wadler 98] presents a very elegant framework and solution, but its specific use here can be simplified to about [20 lines of very straightforward code](http://rextester.com/HNVO8573) (see [full version here](http://rextester.com/BAH4825)).

## Purpose Of A Pretty Printing Library And `Doc`

Many documents and data structures are (multiway) tree-like:

- JSON, [*YANG*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YANG), and basically any document with a hierarchal structure
- many [purely functional data structures](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf)

Therefore, it makes sense to factor out tree pretty-printing, from the actual source of the tree-like data. This factored out library will just contain methods to construct some abstract `Doc` from tree-like data, and pretty print this `Doc`. The point, therefore, is to service several types of sources at once.

To simplify things, let's focus on a particularly simple source:

```
data Tree = Tree String [Tree]
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

which can be constructed like this, for example:

```
tree = 
    Tree "a" [
        Tree "b" [
            Tree "c" []],
        Tree "d" [
            Tree "e" [],
            Tree "f" [],
            Tree "g" [],
            Tree "h" []
        ],
        Tree "i" []
    ]
```

## Prettiness Criteria

Again, for a specific simple example, the criteria for "prettiness" is folding nested elements as much as possible, as long as the result does not exceed some specified length. So, for example, for the above `tree`, if we are given length 30, the prettiest output is defined to be

```
a[[c] d[e, f, g, h] i]
```

if we are given 20

```
a[
    b[c]
    d[e, f, g, h]
    i
]
```

and if we are given 8

```
a[
    b[c]
    d[
        e,
        f,
        g,
        h
    ]
    i
]
```

## An Implementation Of `Doc`

The following is a simplification of [Walder 98].

Any tree can be expressed by a combination of two types:

- a text node, containing a string
- a nest node, containing the indentation level, an opening string, child nodes, and a closing text node

Additionally, any node can be folded or not.

In order to represent this, we can use the following:

```
data Doc = 
      Text String Int 
    | Nest Int String [Doc] String Int
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

- The `Text` type contains just  a `String` of the content
- The `Nest` type contains

  - an `Int` indicating the indentation
  - a `String` indicating the start element
  - a `[Doc]` indicating child elements
  - a `String` indicating the closing element
  - an `Int` indicating the total length of this node, should it be folded

We can easily find the length a `Doc` will have, if folded, using this:

```
getDocFoldedLength :: Doc -> Int
getDocFoldedLength (Text s) = length s
getDocFoldedLength (Nest _ _ _ _ l) = l
```

To create a `Nest`, we use the following:

```
nest :: Int -> String -> [Doc] -> String -> Doc
nest indent open chs close = 
    Nest indent open chs close (length open + length chs - 1 + sum (map getDocFoldedLength chs) + length close)
```

Note that the folded-version length is calculated once, and then "cached".

Getting the folded-version length of a `Doc` in *O(1)* is easy:

```
getDocFoldedLength :: Doc -> Int
getDocFoldedLength (Text s) = length s
getDocFoldedLength (Nest _ _ _ _ l) = l
```

If we will decide to actually fold a `Doc`, we will also need the folded version of its content:

```
getDocFoldedString :: Doc -> String
getDocFoldedString (Nest _ open cs close _) = open ++ intercalate " " (map getDocFoldedString cs) ++ close
getDocFoldedString (Text s) = s
```

Constructing a `Doc` from a tree can be done like this:

```
showTree :: Tree -> Doc
showTree (Tree s ts) = if null chs then Text s else nest (1 + length s) (s ++ "[") chs "]" where
    chs = intercalateDocs "," $ map showTree ts
```

where `intercalateDocs` is a utility function, intercalating commas between non-`Nest` `Docs`:

```
intercalateDocs :: String -> [Doc] -> [Doc]
intercalateDocs _ l | length l < 2 = l
intercalateDocs delim (hd:tl) = case hd of 
    (Text s) -> (Text (s ++ delim)):intercalateDocs delim tl
    otherwise -> hd:intercalateDocs delim tl
```

E.g., for `tree` above `showTree tree` gives

```
Nest 2 "a[" [Nest 2 "b[" [Text "c"] "]" 4,Nest 2 "d[" [Text "e,",Text "f,",Text "g,",Text "h"] "]" 13,Text "i"] "]" 23
```

Now for the heart of the matter, a `pretty` function, deciding which nested elements to fold. Since each `getDocElement` gives us the length of the folded-version of a `Doc`, we can efficiently decide whether to fold or not:

```
pretty :: Int -> Doc -> String
pretty w doc = pretty' 0 w doc where
    pretty' i _ (Text s) = replicate i ' ' ++ s
    pretty' i w (Nest j open cs close l) | i + j + l <= w = 
        replicate i ' ' ++ open ++ intercalate " " (map getDocFoldedString cs) ++ close
    pretty' i w (Nest j open cs close l) = 
        replicate i ' ' ++ open ++ "\n" ++ intercalate "\n" (map (pretty' (i + j) w) cs) ++ "\n" ++ replicate i ' ' ++ close
```

The function `pretty' i w doc` transforms `doc` into a pretty form, assuming the current indentation is `i`, and the width is `w`. Specifically,

- it transforms any `Text` to its string
- it folds any `Nest` if it fits; if not, it calls itself recursively on the children.

(See [full version here](http://rextester.com/BAH4825).)

## Differences From The Paper And Chapter

The papers use solutions that are more elegant and Haskell-Specific. The `Doc`'s algebraic data type includes also a "horizontal concatenation", that generates a sequence of documents depending on whether it (and the descendants) will be folded or not. A careful search doesn't generate all possible documents (whose number is exponential), but rather discards generating large numbers of layouts that cannot possibly be part of the optimal solution. The solution here achieves the same complexity by caching the folded length within each node, which is simpler.

The chapter uses a slightly different API for compatibility with existing Haskell Pretty-Printing libraries. It organizes the code into modules. It also deals with practical JSON-specific problems such as escaping (which is unrelated to pretty printing).

Comment: Small remark: for headings you want to use `# heading` instead of `** heading **`. The first will generate `<h*>` elements, which are semantically more fitting than `<strong>` elements.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks! Did not know that.

Comment: Since you've just worked though chapter 5, would you say that it's out of date? Or still on-topic? [Asking for this wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727768/which-parts-of-real-world-haskell-are-now-obsolete-or-considered-bad-practice/23733494#23733494).

Comment: @zeta I really have no idea, as I'm not very proficient in Haskell, unfortunately.

Comment: No problem. Maybe the remarks will come in handy if you follow RWH further.

Comment: Regarding lines like _the `Text` type contains_, they should be corrected, as `Text` (et similia) is a _value constructor_, whereas `Doc` is the _type constructor_ (and the name of the _type_ too). I'm pretty new to Haskell, but I think the terminology in this answer could be improved (and made more in line with the book) to make it more useful for readers (like me).